# how to move between different classes when click on tab bar item in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

It might look simple but i am not able to figure it out for xcode 4.2. In older version there are option to set viewController but here i am not getting how to do.

In a view i have tab bar.I have added four items likes Services,history,favourites.

When i click on a Services it  should move to serviceview class i mean .xib view of service class.when i click on history it should move to a .xib view of history class.so how do i do this?please anyone help me with sample code.Bcoz  when i went through other tutorials there is a option in xib to set the view controller but in xcode 4.2 there is no option. so can anyone help me in doing this with sample code.

Comment: If you disable 'Storyboard' while creating the project, then it would be like the previous one with `nib` files.

Comment: @Aadhira how do u disable storyBoard?i dont want to do this in storyBoard.After launching application it uses storyBoard.Later i  have added subclass of UIviewController in that i have added tab bar.But there is no option to select .xib filename or anything

Comment: While creating the project, you should disable (uncheck) the checkbox `Use Storyboard`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nib file should look like this:

[image: Xib]

You have to add ViewControllers or NavigationControllers to your TabBarController.
Drag and drop them from the side menu.

Then select your class:

[image: Class]

And the nib file:

[image: Nib]

Comment: u mean to say i should have different views in same .xib file?what i need is different UIView subclass.example i want to click on history item in tab bar that should move to history .xib. can this happen?or should i add views to the same .xib file???

Comment: No... You have more than one xib. What I mean is that you add a TableBarController in your root view and then as many NavigationController as you need. After that you select your NavigationController and change its class and nib. For example if you have a ViewController called myViewController (.h and .m) and a nib called myViewControllerNib.xib, you have to change Class to myViewController and NIB Name to myViewControllerNib.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click on the view of the tab item and then in the identity inspector change the class name to the class of the view you wish to be displayed. Then in the attributes inspector change the nib name to the .xib filename.

Comment: There is no option of .xib filename in attribute inspector in xcode 4.2. i am using xcode 4.2